# Make Forever's watch option (-w) ignore the * .log files in NODEjs

Tags: node.js, forever, forever-monitor

I'm installing NewRelic services in my nodejs app, but having the option -w (watch) active in forever, this one restart my app every time the log NewRelic is modified. Getting the following message:

```
error: Because restarting script changed /home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/app.js
error: Script restart Attempt # 0
(Node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners () to Increase limit.
Trace
    at Agent.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js: 160: 15)
    at initialize (/home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/express.js:100:9)
    at instrument (/home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:50:22)
    at _postLoad (/home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:81:5)
    at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] (/home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:235:16)
    at Module.require (module.js: 364: 17)
    at require (module.js: 380: 17)
    at Object. <anonymous> (/home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/routes/login.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js: 456: 26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js: 474: 10)
    at Module.Load (module.js: 356: 32)
error: Script restart Attempt # 1
error: Because restarting script changed /home/MyProject/public_html/MyProject-api/newrelic_agent.log
```

**QUESTION**: Can I tell Forever ignore the newrelic_agent.log. Or it's not that the problem?

I try with the .foreverignore file => *.log , but it's not working.

NODE VERSION: v0.10.26

Thanks

Comment: I discover someone else with the same problem in the Newrelic Forum:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/node-agent-sends-kill-signal-to-our-server/15429/4